# Simple array question in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Not sure if there is a built in function to do this, so I thought I would ask before I waste the time of writing one. Lets say I have an array:

```
Array
    (
        ['first_name'] => John
        ['last_name'] => Doe
        ['ssn1'] => 123
        ['ssn2'] => 45
        ['ssn3'] => 6789
    )
```

How can I create new key `['ssn']` which will combine the values of the other three, to result in the following:

```
Array
    (
        ['first_name'] => John
        ['last_name'] => Doe
        ['ssn'] => 123456789
    )
```

It comes in separated because there are 3 separate inputs like such `[   ]-[  ]-[    ]` to keep the user from screwing it up. So, what would be the most effective/elegant way of doing this? Thanks!

**Edit**

Looks like most came up with the same simple solution. Have to give it the first. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this data comes from a web form, you could use the input naming convention to your advantage.  Name the elements in order first_name, last_name, ssn[1], ssn[2], ssn[3].  $_REQUEST will automatically assign the three elements to a structured array.

```
<input type="text" name="ssn[1]" />
<input type="text" name="ssn[2]" />
<input type="text" name="ssn[3]" />

array
  'ssn' => 
    array
      1 => string '123' (length=3)
      2 => string '456' (length=3)
      3 => string '7890' (length=4)
```

Then you can simply

```
$_POST['ssn'] = implode('-', $_POST['ssn']);
```

Simple and clean.

Comment: Question though. You are imploding at '-', why/how is this?

Comment: '-' is the "glue" for the array pieces. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php for more info.

Comment: Only trouble I had was, it does not seem to implode them in the order I specify the array in, just the order it comes in as.. If that makes sense (date of birth formatting)

Answer (score 4):

```
$arr['ssn'] = $arr['ssn1'] . $arr['ssn2'] . $arr['ssn3'];
unset($arr['ssn1'], $arr['ssn2'], $arr['ssn3']);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the most naive solution, **using a simple concatenation** :

```
$your_array['ssn'] = $your_array['ssn1'] . $your_array['ssn2'] . $your_array['ssn3'];
```

And you can then **[`unset`](http://www.php.net/unset) the items that are not useful anymore** :

```
unset($your_array['ssn1'], $your_array['ssn2'], $your_array['ssn3']);
```

Maybe that code looks *too naive* -- but it's easy to write, and, even more important, very easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
$data['ssn']=$data['ssn1'].$data['ssn2'].$data['ssn3'];
unset ($data['ssn1'],$data['ssn2'],$data['ssn3']);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
implode( array_intersect_key( $array, array_flip(
  array_filter( array_keys($array), create_function(
    '$k', 'return stristr($k, "ssn");'
  )))
)));
```

This is probably painfully slow compared to just manually concatenating the values, but it was fun to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

You can use implode("",$array) to implode the whole array into a new variable

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php

Comment: This will not work in my scenario unfortunately. I need to keep the other keys/values intact.

Comment: It wont touch the orignal Array ? $newarray = implode("",$array); will make a String out of the old array

Comment: Which will cause the name values to be imploded as well.

Comment: make a new array with only the values you want to have... implode it... or do it like Justin posted ;)

Comment: This seems like the most steps does it not?